# spread syntax doesn't work with node 6.10

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, spread-syntax

i am playing with spread syntax on node/browser.

```
 console.log([{ name: "herry" }, { age: "10" }].reduce((acc, cur) => ({...cur,...acc})))
```

1) with nodejs v6.10,

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

2) Chrome 50

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
```

3) babel stage-0, it's working well.

I am just wandering why it's not working on node 6.10 since it's all green for spread op.

http://node.green/

Comment: That refers to spreading arrays. You are trying to spread an object, which Node does not currently support.

Comment: right, spreading an object is not supported on node yet.

Answer (score 2):

To get this working:

```
yarn add -D babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread # (or the npm equivalent)
```

Then add "transform-object-rest-spread" to your .babelrc plugins e.g.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

Comment: Cool it works!   Also I used workaround 'Object.assign' like this, console.log([{ name: "herry" }, { age: "10" }].reduce((acc, cur) => (Object.assign({}, cur, acc))))

Comment: Thanks @RoguePoster, that got me scratching my head a little.